# Getting Core Bluetooth Service and Characteristic Strings

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth

I'm in the process of writing a CoreBluetooth driver in Swift, and I'm discovering services and characteristics.

One thing that I've noticed, is that the Apple operating system always returns standard Bluetooth characteristics and services as strings instead of raw UUIDs, identifying them.

For example, instead of saying "180A", the log will say "Device Information," or somesuch.

I see these in English. I have no idea if they are localized.

I'd like to be able to access these values for my own purposes (logging and debugging), but I can't find them listed anywhere.

Is there a known, standard place that publishes a glossary that I could use? The best, of course, would be if I could access the Apple pages, but I don't see anything in CoreBluetooth that describes this.

Otherwise, I need to set up my own glossary.